# google analytics not logging refer ~ have i done something wrong?

Tags: google-analytics

probably something simple

how do i get google analytics to detect traffic that comes from a website that redirects to another?

i.e

someone visits www.abc.com, and are redirected to another site

```
<?php header("Location:www.cde.com"); ?>
```

how do i track these hits? nothing comes up..as i guess it's not strictly a "referrer".

hope this makes sense..thanks

or is there a better way to do this? I want to track hits on anyone visiting domain X, which redirects to another site. Essentially we are doing a radio campaign with this new domain and would like to measure its effectiveness.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers don't pass the original referrer through a 302 redirect, so it's not available for Google Analytics to report on.  Apparently if you set a 301 status code *before* the Location then it will work as expected (the php documentation isn't clear on what happens if you set the status code in the third param of the *header* function).

It might be worth setting up GA campaign tracking on this link, check out the GA docs.

Answer (score 0):

The following resource explains how to do this correctly.  Scroll to the bottom to see the "Correct serverside redirect":

http://code.google.com/p/ga-demos/wiki/GaRedirects